# How to upload files to SAP automatically by using VBA

Tags: vba, file, upload

I want a very stable way to upload files to SAP by using VBA.

Below code works in some PCs but doesn't work in other PCs.
It also worked in my PC just after a new installation of Windows, but doesn't work now a few days later. It seems that this problem is caused by Windows setting.

I would like to get some help to amend this code or a totally new way of uploading.

---

```
filepath = rng.Offset(0, 20)
If filepath <> "" Then
    Wshell.Run "C:\Temp\code.vbs " & filepath & " " & "Open File", 0, False
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAB_MAIN/tabpTSMAIN/ssubSCR_MAIN:SAPLCV110:0102/btnPB_FILE_BROWSER").press
```

<< code.vbs>>

```
set Wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do 
bWindowFound = Wshell.AppActivate(WScript.Arguments(1)) 
WScript.Sleep 2000
Loop Until bWindowFound

Wshell.sendkeys "%n"  'alt + n

Wshell.sendkeys WScript.Arguments(0)
WScript.Sleep 200

Wshell.sendkeys "%o"  'alt + o
WScript.Sleep 200
```

Comment: `SendKeys` is known to unreliable, even blocked on some machines, so use code that doesn't depend on the user interface.

Comment: Please note the following link: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/26/new-scripting-option-in-sap-gui-for-windows-730-pl-8/                                Normally the property 'Show native MS Windows dialogs' should be deactivated. Then you would have to re-record the part of the script at this point and use it instead of the outdated construction with SendKeys.

Comment: tks for your hopeful reply. I tried but in fail because I don't know the detailed way to get script in Show native Microsoft dialogs. Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: If you have made the recommended setting in SAP, you would have to carry out a new recording of the script as shown in the link: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/08/04/script-recording-playback-for-dummies/                              You can also get a suggestion from this link:  https://blogs.sap.com/2012/11/19/how-to-select-a-specific-session-to-do-sap-gui-scripting-activities-inside-it/